# Rails 4: render controller/action again when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

There are already a couple of questions addressing this issue:

- [render/redirect to new action when validation fails (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077505/render-redirect-to-new-action-when-validation-fails-rails)
- [Keeping validation errors after redirect from partial back to the same page that has the partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095883/keeping-validation-errors-after-redirect-from-partial-back-to-the-same-page-that)

I tried to implement some of the solutions recommended but did not manage fixing my issue.

So here we go.

In my Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :invites
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Here, we are going to focus on the `Invite` and the `Calendar` models.

In the calendar `edit` view, I have a form to `create` a new invite:

```
<h2>Edit <%= @calendar.name %> calendar</h2>

<%= render 'form' %>

<h2>Invite new users to <%= @calendar.name %> calendar</h2>

<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :calendar_id, :value => @invite.calendar_id %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.label "Role" %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:recipient_role, "Editor") %>
    <%= f.label "Editor" %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:recipient_role, "Viewer") %>
    <%= f.label "Viewer" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', calendar_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', calendars_path %>
```

–––––

**UPDATE**: please note that I have defined a `calendars.html.erb` layout for my calendar views, including the following code to display alerts:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
    <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

–––––

In the `Invite` model, I want to validate the presence of `:email` and `:recipient_role` (both values submitted by the user through the form), so I added this to the `Invite` model:

```
validates :email, :recipient_role, presence: true
```

And I would like users to be redirected to the form with an error message if they forgot to fill one of these two fields, which I implemented with the following code in the `InvitesController`:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # some code
    if @invite.save
      # some code
    else
      format.html { render :template => "calendars/edit", notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.' }
    end
    redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Invitation was successfully sent.'
  end

  private

  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:email, :calendar_id, :recipient_role)
  end

end
```

In particular, I thought that the line `format.html { render :template => "calendars/edit", notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.' }` would allow me to do what I wanted, [as recommended here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller).

However, when I try to submit the form with at least an empty field, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in InvitesController#create
too few arguments
end
    else
      format.html { render :template => "calendars/edit", notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.' }
    end
    redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Invitation was successfully sent.'
  end
```

And this is the server log:

```
Processing by InvitesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p+yxM9Tw3JiNw/6Chv9//N8uvWhMy0TqrudTu0y9D9zXCl6kK2LtCqPu1rvTGv5gOMBuv2RK/IX2MBpWUTelZw==", "invite"=>{"calendar_id"=>"3", "email"=>"test@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

ArgumentError (too few arguments):
  app/controllers/invites_controller.rb:16:in `format'
  app/controllers/invites_controller.rb:16:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (54.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (36.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (83.2ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you should `redirect` when the invitation is saved. ie moving this part of code to the `if` condition `redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Invitation was successfully sent.'` and in the else part remove the `format.html` and simply write this `render :template => "calendars/edit", notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.'` will this help.

Comment: Thanks, this actually fixed the problem. Do you want to suggest this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure. let me add it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following things please

```
def create
  # some code
  if @invite.save
    redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Invitation was successfully sent.'
  else
    render template: "calendars/edit", notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.'
  end
end
```